# Display points fitted to x Axis

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I´m trying to add an array of points to a chartXY but the chart isn´t properly drawn. The Y Values appears well fitted to Axis but x values aren't. The series appears in the middle of the chart like a line.

The code that generates the chart and adds points is the next below:

```
this.chart1 = lightningChart().ChartXY({ containerId: this.chartId1, defaultAxisXTickStrategy: AxisTickStrategies.Numeric })
        .setBackgroundFillStyle(new SolidFill({color: ColorHEX( '#C6C2C1' )}))
        .setChartBackgroundFillStyle(new SolidFill({color: ColorHEX( '#FFFFFF' )}))
        .setTitle('LightningCharts 1')
        .setTitleFillStyle(new SolidFill({color: ColorHEX( '#000000' )}));
// Fijo las propiedades del eje y
this.chart1.getDefaultAxisY()
    .setTitle('mV')
    .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.fitting)
    .setAnimationScroll(false)
    .fit(true)
    .setAnimationZoom(undefined)
    .setTitleFillStyle(new SolidFill({color: ColorHEX( '#000000' )}))
    .setTickStyle(new VisibleTicks({ labelFillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#000000')}), tickLength: 20 }));

// Fijo las propiedades del eje x
this.chart1.getDefaultAxisX()
    .setTitle('milliseconds')
    .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.fitting)
    .setAnimationScroll(false)
    .fit(true)
    .setAnimationZoom(undefined)
    .setTitleFillStyle(new SolidFill({color: ColorHEX( '#000000' )}))
    .setTickStyle(new VisibleTicks({ labelFillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#000000')}) }));
// Añado las series al chart
// tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
this.lineSeries1 = this.chart1.addPointLineSeries({ dataPattern: DataPatterns.horizontalProgressive, xAxis: this.chart1.getDefaultAxisX() })
    .setName('Serie 1')
    .setStrokeStyle( new SolidLine({
      thickness: 2,
      fillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX( '#E72B1C' ) })
    }))
    .setMouseInteractions(false);


this.lineSeries1.add(this.points);
```

And the array of points I´m generating with this code:

```
this.points = [];
// const sign = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + 1)) === 0 ? -1 : 1;
const firstX = Date.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
  const point = {
    x: firstX + (i * 1000),
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * (5000 + 1))
  };
  this.points.push(point);
}
```

How can I see data fitted in the x Axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LightningChart JS currently can't support such large numbers on the Axis well. There is a limit on the axis interval when working with large numbers.

You can work around this issue by starting the X axis values from 0 or by editing the Numeric axis tick strategy.

---

Editing the tick strategy is not well supported and will change in future but for now it can be done.

First you need to ensure that the chart is created with a copy of the [Numeric](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.2/globals.html#axistickstrategies.numeric) AxisTickStrategy.

```js
const chart1 = ChartXY({
    defaultAxisXTickStrategy: Object.assign({}, AxisTickStrategies.Numeric)
})
```

The `Object.assign` is the key here. This will create a copy of the Numeric axis tick strategy.

Now that the chart has been created, it is possible to edit the tick strategy.

```js
chart1.getDefaultAxisX().tickStrategy.formatValue = (value, range) => {
    return (offset + value).toFixed(0)
}
```

With this code an `offset` is added to the displayed values. This offset shouldn't exist in the data itself, it's only added when the data is displayed. The `formatValue` function is called always when the data is displayed by LightningChart JS.

See the code snippet below for a full implementation.

```js
const points = [];
// const sign = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + 1)) === 0 ? -1 : 1;
const firstX = 0;
const offset = Date.now()
for (let i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
    const point = {
        x: firstX + (i * 1000),
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * (5000 + 1))
    };
    points.push(point);
}

const {
    lightningChart,
    SolidFill,
    AxisTickStrategies,
    VisibleTicks,
    ColorHEX,
    AxisScrollStrategies,
    DataPatterns,
    SolidLine
} = lcjs

const chart1 = lightningChart().ChartXY({
    containerId: 'target',
    defaultAxisXTickStrategy: Object.assign({}, AxisTickStrategies.Numeric)
})
    .setBackgroundFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#C6C2C1') }))
    .setChartBackgroundFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#FFFFFF') }))
    .setTitle('LightningCharts 1')
    .setTitleFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#000000') }));
chart1.getDefaultAxisX().tickStrategy.formatValue = (value, range) => {
    return (offset + value).toFixed(0)
}
// Fijo las propiedades del eje y
chart1.getDefaultAxisY()
    .setTitle('mV')
    .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.fitting)
    .setAnimationScroll(false)
    .fit(true)
    .setAnimationZoom(undefined)
    .setTitleFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#000000') }))
    .setTickStyle(new VisibleTicks({ labelFillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#000000') }), tickLength: 20 }));

// Fijo las propiedades del eje x
chart1.getDefaultAxisX()
    .setTitle('milliseconds')
    .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.fitting)
    .setAnimationScroll(false)
    .fit(true)
    .setAnimationZoom(undefined)
    .setTitleFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#000000') }))
    .setTickStyle(new VisibleTicks({ labelFillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#000000') }) }));
// Añado las series al chart
// tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
const lineSeries1 = chart1.addPointLineSeries({ dataPattern: DataPatterns.horizontalProgressive, xAxis: chart1.getDefaultAxisX() })
    .setName('Serie 1')
    .setStrokeStyle(new SolidLine({
        thickness: 2,
        fillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#E72B1C') })
    }))
    .setMouseInteractions(false);


lineSeries1.add(points);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.2.2/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
<div style="height: 100%;" id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Why is not well supported and in the future how will I solve the problem with large numbers?
The idea is to use the lighningChart js library in a serious project and I need something that works well now and in the future, and if I have to change in the future it has to be an easy solution.

Comment: The method I have shown will work in all v1.x.x versions of LightningChart JS. So the method will be safe to use with all minor and patch releases of LightningChart JS. In future, with a major release (v2.0.0), the way the formattingFunction is set will change a little It will most likely have a setter function. The functionality itself will stay same, just different way of setting the formatting function.